# How Can I Speed-up WebSphere Deployments?

Tags: deployment, websphere, websphere-6.1

**Problem:** A 10 to 15 minute delay in WebSphere application deployments.

**Environment/Situation:** WebSphere 6.1.0.23, 90MB ear files containing about 19,000 files (ear file contains jar libraries).  The ear file, WebSphere, and the automation driving the deployment are all on the same box. No EJBs. There are about 20 deployed applications like this on this box with 10 of them usually running.

**Details:** The deployment is automated, and the message 'ADMA5013I: Application ... installed successfully' is received.  A few moments later, the directory is created (blah.ear/blah.war), but the directory remains empty for 10 to 15 minutes.  Except for this specific delay, the performance on the box is fine and CPU utilization is very low.  Once the files start getting created, they all show up in under a minute.  Steps before and after this step run at an acceptable speed.  It's just this one step, waiting for the files to show-up that's the problem.

**Additional Details** (precipitated by comments, below): WebSphere ND as evidenced by "Deployment Manager", and "Node Agent" in the logs.  The ear contains one war file, one application.  By using shared a library definition, the size of the ear was reduced to 60MB.  WebSphere itself is started with JVM option -XX:MaxPermSize=256M.  The deployments are done using the tools in the com.ibm.websphere.management.* packages (jar file supplied by IBM), primary class is "AdminClient". The code is similar to what is in [this IBM documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tjmx_develop.html)   WS UI entry [System Administration > Console Preferences > "Synchronize changes with nodes"] was checked, but still sits for 15 minutes 'without doing anything'.

Comment: 90KB or 90MB? How many modules within single EAR? How much memory is allocated for WAS? What WAS edition do you have? How exactly the deployment is being done?

Comment: Are you using ND?  "Node sync" is required for prompt configuration updates.

Comment: 90 megabytes, yes, sorry.  Edited the original question.  The "edition", I'm not sure how to tell, although I think it might be "ND".  The deployments are done using the tools in

Comment: The deployments are done using the tools in the com.ibm.websphere.management.* packages (jar file supplied by IBM), primary class is "AdminClient".  Is there an easy way to tell if it's "ND"?

Comment: By ND, I meant: are you starting a deployment manager, node agent, and application server in your environment?

Comment: Yes.  I see "Deployment Manager", and "Node Agent" in the logs.  When I go the UI I see my applications when I go into "Servers > Application Servers".  I am currently researching all of the AppDeploymentTask.setTaskData(String[][]) entries in this deployment code to find anything to do with "Node sync".

Comment: In the WebSphere console, System Administration > Console Preferences > Synchronize changes with nodes was unchecked.  I changed that to be checked (true) rather than try to force a node sync via deployment code.

Comment: The "Synchronize changes with nodes" setting did not make any difference.  WebSphere itself is started with  -XX:MaxPermSize=256M.

Comment: The "Synchronize changes with nodes" setting should indeed make this happen faster, but I expect only if you're deploying through the console. If you're automating deployment through scripts, I'm not surprised this setting doesn't affect it.

Comment: Have you tried collecting a javacore dump from the Websphere java process during the 10-15 minute period where no files are being written? The javacore may shed some light on what Websphere is doing during this time period: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21138203#javacores

Answer (score 0):

Just guesses:

1. ear files timestamp is in the past. Might be caused by jvm time-zone problems, different    time zones when building/deploying (esp. if different machines used).
2. JDK could determine is there enough disk space
3. WSAD of some tool do not close file descriptor. Try deploy with anti-viruses paused.

Could you please describe situation in more details:

- does build and deploy on the same machine?
- does it work the same on all circumstances?